# image for training back propagation

Tags: image

can someone explain about this source code. its image processing for training back propagation. I want binary as my input for training but it's not working. I have about 500 images to process in matlab.

```
clc
close all
clear all
feature_extraction = [];
feature_extra = [];
j1=1;
j2=1;
for j=1:500
        RGB = imread(['frame',num2str(j),'.jpg']);
    img_crop = RGB;
    I= rgb2gray(RGB);
    I = imresize(I,[80 64],'bicubic');
      figure, imshow(I);
          BW = edge(I,'canny',0.25); %Finding the edges of the image
      [imx,imy]=size(BW);
      msk=[0 0 0 0 0;
          0 1 1 1 0;
          0 1 1 1 0;
          0 1 1 1 0;
          0 0 0 0 0;];
      B=conv2(double(BW),double(msk)); %smoothing the image to reduce the number of connected components
      figure,imshow(B);
       A=im2bw(B);
          bw_resize=imresize(A,[70,50]);
      data_target(j1,j2) = 1;
      j2 = j2+1;
      end
          j1 = j1+1;
  end
```